# C# Directory.Delete Throwing Illegal Character Error

Tags: c#

So we have an application where users keep losing their toolbars and the only way to fix the issue is to delete a folder in the appdata for that user. So we wrote a simple little program that deletes this folder here is the error we are getting in the `try catch`

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.InternalCombine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String path, Boolean recursive)
   at DeleteFolder.frnDeleteFolder.btnDelete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\rmcintosh.K12.000\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\DeleteFolder\DeleteFolder\frnDeleteFolder.cs:line 82
```

Here is the code we are using to delete

```
   string path = @"C:\Users\98532153\AppData\Roaming\DraftSight";
    try
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path)) {
            Directory.Delete(path, true);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Directory Does Not Exists");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to point out this works find as long as the main directory is empty, but as soon as I add any file subdirectory it throws this error.

Comment: Check to make sure you do not have extra quotes in the path and that the path does not end in a slash.

Comment: removed slash at end of path.

Comment: Try this `string path = @"C:\Users\98532153\AppData\Roaming\DraftSight";`

Comment: Is this the actual code? 'Cause this `string path = "C:\Users\98532153\AppData\Roaming\DraftSight";` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Amazing that this string literal even compiled.

Comment: The only thing I changed was `string path = txtPath.Text;` to `string path = "C:\Users\98532153\AppData\Roaming\DraftSight";`

Comment: Reduce the problem to a one-line repro that everybody can execute. This is easy in this case.

Comment: Did you build after that? 'Cause it should give a compilation error with that string literal.

Comment: A more interesting question is why the `Directory.Exists` call succeeds. Seems like that should return `false` if the path has invalid characters.

Comment: Modified the path to be `@"C:\Users\98532153\AppData\Roaming\DraftSight";` This did compile for me, and I still get the same error

Comment: @JimMischel I never even thought to see if that is what was causing the error... Commented that check out and it deleted with no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslash in a C# string is an escape character; you either need `string path = @"C:\Whatever\Wherever";` -- note the '@' -- or you need `string path = "C:\\Whatever\\Wherever";` -- note the double-backslashes.

You can read more about [string literals on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some sub-directories deep inside may have some invalid characters in their names. Somehow .NET not handling it. Only way is to write your own routine, check the path recursively and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the Intellisense in VS it tells you that the directory must be empty.

call Directory.GetFiles and purge them thendelete the directory.

if you need I can help you with a recursive method to do this.

Comment: `Directory.Delete(path, true)` Deletes all files and Directories recursively. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx